# If I have the Covid virus, should I consider using O2 at all altitudes while engaged in GA aviation?

Tags: general-aviation, emergency-procedures

If I have the Covid virus, should I consider using O2 at all altitudes while engaged in GA aviation as PIC?  To combat decreases in physiological functioning due to the virus?

Comment: Shouldn't you just stay on the ground until you're over it?  Or are you talking about having had a severe case and  recovering but with lung damage?

Comment: This seems like a medical question, not an aviation one. The answer might also be different for different people. Although personally I'd say that if you're even asking the question then you shouldn't be flying.

Comment: The bigger problem is you’re endangering anyone you’re with.  A masked person who has COVID (e.g. but doesn’t know it) will not spread it to others; their mask stops it.  That is why it is so important everyone wear masks.  However this fails if the mask has an exhalation valve, which I bet your mask does.

Answer (score 15):

IMSAFE

If you have an illness (especially one that requires medication, or puts stress on your body, or causes a decrease in performance, or induces fatigue), you should not fly as PIC. For your own health and safety, you should probably not fly at a reduced cabin pressure at all until cleared by a physician.